# .cfg file to .awk file

Tags: shell-script, awk

My color.cfg file from where I am reading a file is as below.

```
marks,<,80,green
marks,>,80,yellow
```

I want to convert above color.cfg file into color.awk as below

```
function check()
{
if ( marks < 80 )
 return "green"
if (marks > 800)
return "yellow"
}
```

I have a shell script like below to convert .cfg to .awk.

```
LINECT=0

while read LINE
 do
 var1[$LINECT]=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f1)
 var2[$LINECT]=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f2)
 var3[$LINECT]=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f3)
 var4[$LINECT]=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ',' -f4)
 LINECT=$((LINECT+1))
 done < color.cfg

echo ${var1[@]}
echo ${var2[@]}
echo ${var3[@]}
echo ${var4[@]}

echo $LINECT

cat <<EOF > color.awk
function check()
{
if (${var1[0]} ${var2[0]} ${var3[0]} )
return "${var4[0]}"
}

EOF
```

My problem is how to write repetitive “if blocks” while writing a color.awk

I have written “if block once but how to write if have 2 or 3 or 4 condition ?

```
cat <<EOF > color.awk
function check()
{
if (${var1[0]} ${var2[0]} ${var3[0]} )
return "${var4[0]}"
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to use an `awk` script to create an `awk` function...

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
function check() {
        if (marks < 80) return "green"
        if (marks > 80) return "yellow"
}
```

Where `script.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    printf("function check() {\n")
}

{
    printf("\tif (%s %s %s) return \"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)
}

END {
    printf("}\n")
}
```

This simply loops over the lines in the comma-separated file and uses the fields to output `if` and `return` statements.  There will be as many of these as there are lines in the input file.

I let the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks do the function header and footer, and the `BEGIN` block additionally sets the input field separator to a comma.

No check for valid input is performed.  This would probably go into the main block in the body of the script.

Redirect the output of the script to a file, e.g. `color.awk`.

Adding an extra line to the input file,

```
marks,==,80,red
```

would result in

```
function check() {
        if (marks < 80) return "green"
        if (marks > 80) return "yellow"
        if (marks == 80) return "red"
}
```

Related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)